# Qual o significado da versão do kernel?

Tags: android, kernel

Estou tentando fazer um aplicativo, como trabalho de faculdade, para diagnóstico de vulnerabilidade do Android com base em metadados do dispositivo, como versão do Android, versão do Kernel, Build Number, etc.

Eu não compreendo totalmente a string da versão do kernel que pode ser verificada nas configurações do dispositivo.

No meu dispositivo, por exemplo (Samsung Win Duos), a string da versão do kernel é:

Kernel version:

```
3.4.0-1565445
se.infra@SWDB2914 #1
SMP PEEMPT Wed Aug 13 03:54:31 KST 2014
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que significa exatamente cada um dos elementos desta string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu posso ajudar você com algumas coisas:

`3.4.0` é a versão do kernel do linux na qual é baseado.

`se.infra` é a conta de usuário usada no sistema `SWDB2914 #1` para fazer a compilação.

[SMP](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/SMP.html) vem de Symmetric Multiprocessing e PREEMP é de kernel preemptivo, o qual permite a troca de contexto, de aplicações.

Comment: Entendi. Depois de muita pesquisa eu descobri que "Wed Aug 13 03:54:31 KST 2014" é a data de compilação do sistema (kernel). Em um aplicativo isto pode ser obtido através da constante Build.TIME. muito obrigado pela informação, ajudou bastante.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu descobrir tudo,  fico grato por ter ajudado. ;)